# interpretation output aov and contrasts

Tags: r, interpretation, ancova, contrasts

I have a question regarding an output interpretation.
The model can be described as followed

```
model <- lm(variable ~ p1*p2 , data = df)
```

predictor 1 (p1) is fixed, group;

predictor 2 (p2) is continuous, tiredness,

and variable is a testscore.

Now, I set up 3 contrasts

```
mat <- cbind( "A"=c(-1/3, -1/3, -1/3, 1),"B"=c(-1/2,-1/2, 1, 0), "C"=c(-1, 1,0 , 0))
contrasts(df$p1) <- mat
```

Now, I am not sure how to interpret this output

```
> summary.lm(model)

Call:
lm(formula = variable ~ p1 * p2, data = df)

Residuals:
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.73499 -0.31352  0.04792  0.47164  1.21074 

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   3.84715    0.27487  13.996   <2e-16 ***
p1A          -0.83339    0.45499  -1.832   0.0696 .  
p1B           0.40285    0.47043   0.856   0.3936    
p1C           0.01339    0.38644   0.035   0.9724    
p2            0.06174    0.05141   1.201   0.2322    
p1A:p2        0.15982    0.08958   1.784   0.0770 .  
p1B:p2       -0.07540    0.08557  -0.881   0.3801    
p1C:p2        0.01532    0.07084   0.216   0.8292    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.6717 on 116 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.05534,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.001669 
F-statistic: 0.9707 on 7 and 116 DF,  p-value: 0.456
```

Well, it is not significant, that is fine.

The result of the main effects and interaction was not significant (not reported here). Groups did not differ in test score, tiredness does not seem to have an influence on the test score and tiredness does not seem to significantly interact with the test score (again, not reported here).

But what is the correct interpretation of p1A:p2? For example, is it significant?

Thank you very much in advance!